# Am I meant to be able to see a user's negative rep changes?

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-history

If memory serves me correctly, I never used to be able to another user's negative rep changes. Now I may be wrong here but it surprised me when I saw this:

[image]

Am I meant to be able to see this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this isn't a bug.

Other people can see the down-votes you've *received* on your profile. After all if they go to the post the can see the vote breakdown (assuming they have enough rep of course).

It's only the rep loss due to down-votes *given* that they can't see.

Comment: I thought that, but can see downvotes in user profiles on Code Review, where I only have 116 rep. I would have thought I'd have needed 1k, same as is needed to view dvotes in the question/answer.

Comment: @James - I see your point, but I don't *think* this is a bug. You could check on a site without the new profile page.

Comment: Confirmed on Programmers too, which has no new profile page (your profile as it happens) I only have 18 rep. Maybe it's illogical to need 1K rep. If I wanted, I could trawl your profile and find out the up/down votes on a particular question, but it would take ages so doubt it's going to be abused.